# The present perfect: appropriate/grammatical?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

In a sentence like the one below, is the present perfect acceptable?

> This past week I **have learned** all sorts of things.

Would it make more sense to say:

> The past week I **learned** all sorts of things

if it's implied by "past" that my learning of all sorts of things was completed last week? However, the "this" before "past week," to me, makes it seem like the week is still ongoing?

Some additional questions: Is there a difference between these sentences in meaning? Does either sound better than the other?

Comment: This question has been answered in one way or another many times. You might want to search the site. People get confused by this: it is not a grammatical issue only. It is about what you want to say. YOU: Do you want to just say this is past, without saying WHEN: last week, yesterday. OR: do you want to say it was specific and over?  last week and yesterday?? The first takes PP and the second takes SP. Also, a detail: if the week is still going, AND you want to not give a specific time, you say: have  learned.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right in what you say about the tenses, but I want to point out that "this past week" means the week which is just coming to a close.

**This past week I've learned all sorts of things.**

By my intuition, that sentence is just fine, for example if I had just had classes from Monday to Friday. I could say exactly that on Friday afternoon.

**This past week I learned all sorts of things.**

I would say this if the learning which I was talking about had actually ended. For example, after I had left classes for the week, on Friday or any time at the weekend.

**Last week I learned all sorts of things.**

This is something I would say the following week, for example on the Monday morning.